# Configuration, upload and dependencies in gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

I am having a problem building some interdependent modules in a gradle based project. What I want to be able to do is have a project (similar to some maven projects I have worked with), where the dependencies are on each others versions, so when deployed to a maven repository, are available, but building a module builds the dependencies.

To illustrate, I have a gradle project with a few submodules.

```
ProjectA
|- module-a
\- module-b (depends on module-a)
```

In module b, I specify the dependency using `compile "{groupId:module-b:{versionName}`, and in the project root build.gradle, I have

```
project(':module-b') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':module-a')
    }
}
```

Another project with a dependency on the other project.

```
ProjectB
\- module-c (depends on module-b)
```

When building ProjectB, there are errors about not being able to find `ProjectA:module-a:unspecified`. The pom generated for module-b does include that dependency.

If I remove the dependency specification in ProjectA's root `build.gradle`, when I try and build, module-b cannot find module-a (during the dependency resolution phase). module-a would not be deployed anywhere yet, so this makes sense to me.

I would like module-b to depend on it's sibling, but have it's pom show a maven-style version dependency, so that module-c can depend on module-b and transitively get module-a.

(There is no requirement that ProjectB be a gradle project. Either maven or gradle should work.)

**Gradle configuration files**

settings.gradle

```
include 'module-a', 'module-b'
```

build.gradle

```
project(':module-b') {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  dependencies {
    compile project(':module-a')
  }
}
```

module-a/build.gradle

```
group 'com.example.coatedmoose'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      mavenLocal()
    }
  }
}
```

module-b/build.gradle

```
group 'com.example.coatedmoose'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.example.coatedmoose:module-a:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      mavenLocal()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For better understanding could you post your build.gradle and settings.gradle files, please?